# Error de paréntesis derecho a la hora de crear una tabla

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, oracle-sqldeveloper

necesito que me ayuden con el siguiente código que voy a dejar a continuación. El error que me sale es que falta un paréntesis a la derecha, pero yo no veo que falte ninguno. Este es el código:

```
Create Table productos_p (
idProducto number(6) constraint PK_PPRODUCTOS primary key,
nombre varchar2(255) not null,
descripcion varchar2(255) not null,
estado number(1) constraint CK_ESTADOS check(estado BETWEEN 1 AND 5),
precio number(20,2) not null,
foto varchar2(255) not null,
fechaAlta date,
fechaVenta date,
vendedor number(6),
comprador number(6),
idCategoria number(6) FK_PPRODUCTOS_CATEGORIAS references categorias_p);

Insert into productos_p values(
1,'Samsung Galaxy S8','Móvil de gama alta',5,750,'S8.jpg',12/04/2017,05/02/2018,2,1,1);

Insert into productos_p values(
2,'BICICLETA DE CARRETERA BTWIN ULTRA 900 CARBONO BTWIN','Concebido para la práctica del ciclismo de carretera en competición y los entrenamientos intensivos en cualquier trazado',
4, 1499, 'bici.jpg', 19/06/2015, 23/09/2017, 2, 3, 2);

Insert into productos_p values(
3, 'ATRAPADA EN EL TIEMPO',
'Libro que trata sobre la batalla de Culloden', 3, 17,'libro.jpg', 06/02/2016, 17/05/2018, 1, 3, 3);
```

Comment: Te falta especificar la columna del foreign key asi: `idCategoria number(6) FK_PPRODUCTOS_CATEGORIAS references categorias_p(idCategoria));`

Comment: en la parte de references categorias_p te hace falta meter el id de dicha tabla dentro de paréntesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Así debería quedar la declaración de tu tabla

```
Create Table productos_p (
idProducto number(6) constraint PK_PPRODUCTOS primary key,
nombre varchar2(255) not null,
descripcion varchar2(255) not null,
estado number(1) constraint CK_ESTADOS check(estado BETWEEN 1 AND 5),
precio number(20,2) not null,
foto varchar2(255) not null,
fechaAlta date,
fechaVenta date,
vendedor number(6),
comprador number(6),
idCategoria number(6),
CONSTRAINT FK_PPRODUCTOS_CATEGORIAS FOREIGN KEY(idCategoria) references categorias_p(id));
```

> Como puedes observar en un renglón por separado declaro el campo que
>   actuará como llave foránea es decir el idCategoria y en uno por
>   separado declaro el constraint foreing key referenciando dentre
>   parentesis el id de la tabla categorias_p que es de hecho el valor que
>   te hace falta

Answer (score 2):

Un consejo: prueba las tres partes por separado y ve descartando posibes erroes, primero con el script de creacion de tabla, y luego con cada insert independiente, una vez localizaado el error edita esta pregunta. Gracias

Comment: pon esto en la foranea "references 'tablename' (categorias_p)"